# How can I create a new user (visitor - read only) in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

What I find is only adding existing users to a group or creating a new group, but I couldn't find anything that allows me to create new users.
I'm logged in as administrator and there are no more users anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add users to SharePoint using 'stsadm';
take a look at [Adduser: Stsadm operation (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262627.aspx)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks man for your reply, but where shall I write that? in Command Prompt?

Comment: but what is the path i should run that from?

Comment: The bin folder of the 12 hive, i.e. c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\bin.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a new user to your active directory domain, and then add them into your sharepoint site collection as an existing user.

Comment: what is the active directory domain? and how can i do that?

Comment: Refer to this link http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/directory/activedirectory/default.mspx. To Simply put AD is a Place where you can create and manage user and their details. The ID you use to login to the computer is the one created through AD. And to answer your question, you cannot create a User Directly in SharePoint. You can only add an user that is already present in the AD